# Java Reflection: Code runs fine in Debugger but not in "normal" running mode

Tags: java, methods, reflection, nullpointerexception, static

I'm trying to call a static Method from an Array of Methods. This works just fine in the debugger but not in normal running mode.. Why is this?

More description in code comments below..

EDIT for easier reproduction just run this class in Debugger vs. normal Mode:

```
public class Stackoverflowquestion {

public static class Backautomat {
    private String aktuellBackendeBrotsorte = "Butterbrot";
    //Test für Statische Methoden: Brauche ich dazu auch eine Instanz für Invoke? 
    public static String getBezeichnung(){
        return "Bezeichnung: Bester-Backautomat-Ever";
    }
    //Test für Methoden ohne Parameterliste
    public boolean backautomat_starten(){
        return true;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    //Get all methods of class
    Method[] backaudomadMethoden = Backautomat.class.getMethods();
    //Get first Method of class -> I know this one is static -> see in source "Backautomat"
    Method backMethod =  backaudomadMethoden[0];
    //Printing out Method Name: In Debugger this returns the static method name: getBezeichnung(),
    //In "normal" running mode (Run -> Run as -> Java Application) it prints out the second method: backautomat_starten()
    System.out.println(backMethod.getName());
    //Invocation is successfull in debugger
    //Invocation throws exception running in "normal" mode
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(backMethod.invoke(null)));

}
```

EDIT exception looks like this:

```
backautomat_starten Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.relfection.easy.example.Stackoverflowquestion.main(Stackoverflowquestion.java:31)
```

Comment: And what's the exception? Can you provide a [mcve] so we can reproduce it for ourselves without having to copy and paste different bits into different files? (We should be able to create a single new file, copy, paste, compile, run and see the error.)

Comment: [`Class.getMethods()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods--) does not provide the methods in any guaranteed order. So running in the debugger *can* have an effect on the order. In fact, *anything* can have an effect on that order, but the debugger case is even plausible…

Comment: From the doc for `getMethods()`: "The elements in the returned array are not sorted and are not in any particular order."

Comment: If you want to get the right method, just use `Backautomat.class.getMethod("getBezeichnung")`…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the [documentation of `Class.getMethods()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods--):

> …
>
> The elements in the returned array are not sorted and are not in any particular order.

This implies that arbitrary aspects of the current JRE can have the side effect of altering the result, running in the debugger inclusive.

So if the first method in the array is not the one you expect, getting a different name than expected and producing an exception when attempting to run the instance method like a `static` method, are symptoms of the same wrong assumption.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer, that explains the problem. I was just curios because it always works in the debugger but not in normal mode.

Comment: Tracing the actual code path that make the difference can require a very deep dive into the actual implementation. For understanding the issue, it’s enough to understand that certain code to enable the communication between JVM and debugger has to be loaded, which also may have an impact on the order in which certain things are initialized and this might have an effect on such subtle things like the order of the elements return by `getMethods()`. Since it’s unpredictable whether and how long this information is cached, the order might even change for subsequent calls within the same session…

Comment: Okay, well this would go too far. Thank you for your detailed answers!

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...)

This states that you call that method on the passed in defined object

```
String.valueOf(backMethod.invoke(null));
```

Here are you passing in null as the object, so you are trying to call a method on a null object.

Its similar to doing something like

```
Object x = null;
x.toString();
```

and obviously x.toString() would throw the NPE

Comment: Also, the doc states clearly why this would work for a static method :  _If the underlying method is static, then the specified obj argument is ignored. It may be null._

Comment: ah yes, so its just the ordering of the methods returned, so clearly when they are debugging, its in one order, and running normally its another